# How to call MySql Database Through Webservices

Tags: mysql, .net, web-services, wcf

I want to connect MySql Database to asp.net by calling Webservices Wcf but iam not getting correct Solution so, Please Help me by giving any reference link

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can access the DB using ADO.net itself

Please find the below link for more reference and example code

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for Reply but my requirement is to connect MYSQL Database to asp.net Through WCF service